# Is there a way to let the screen always on?

Tags: android, frameworks

My customer want a screen-saver for android, I use the

1. KeyguardManager
2. Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF
3. Ref: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/

When the Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF received, my activity really started. but the screen is off, so I can not see nothing, What I really want is the sreen-saver UI will show on screen.

Is there a way to control the screen on/off programmtically?

Answer (score 0):

You should see [Coding for (Battery) Life Google IO presentation](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/CodingLifeBatteryLife.html), slide 16 for keeping screen on

Comment: Thanks your reminding. In my case, my customer will use an android tablet in kiosk, there are always have charged power, when the application started, client can do some operation, if no operaion in 5 minutes, my customer would like to show some demo in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

see if this helps 
http://www.androidsnippets.com/stop-screen-from-dimming-by-enforcing-wake-lock

Comment: Yes, it give me some clue. I will get the wake lock in my parent activity. It seems not a good idea, but it works for demo phase.